# React, props, state, JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, state

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть следующий код:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import styles from './table.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      VacTitle: '11'
    };
  };


  getApi(id){
    fetch('https://api.hh.ru/vacancies/'+id)
   .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
   })
   .then(function(data) {
     console.log('Request successful', data);
     return data;
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log('Request failed', error)
   });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src="true" onError={this.getApi(this.props.id)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Как вывести data полученный через getAPI в state? Никак не получается(

P.S. Сделал так (onError), так как src нет, функция сработает как window.onLoad :)

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';

import styles from './table.css';

class Vacan extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      VacTitle: '11',
      isLoad: false,
      data: []
    };
  };


  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/vacancies/${this.props.id}`)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => {
     this.setState({
       isLoad: true,
       data: json,
     })
     console.log(json);
   })
  }

  render() {

    var { isLoad, data } = this.state;

    if (!isLoad) {
      return <div>Loading... < /div>
    } else {
      const html = '<h1>'+this.state.data.name+'</h1>' + this.state.data.description;
      return (
        <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Vacan;
```